# Angular $http PUT requests return status -1

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, rest, http-headers

I have a PHP REST API running on Apache2 Webserver inside an Ubuntu machine.

I'm trying to send PUT requests to my server with no success.

When I'm sending the request inside my localhost (same origin) - it works.
When I'm sending the request on my Docker containers (same origin) - it works.

When I'm sending the request from my Angular client to the server in development environment (cross-origin) - I received a weird `status -1` error in the return of the request.

From sending the request from PostMan Chrome Extension - it works perfectly, but I see nothing special in its request headers.

**This is my code for sending the request:**

```
return $http.put(path, params).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

**This is a picture of the returned status:**

[image]

Comment: this seems to be the php response, into the data object.

Comment: It's not the data. It's the response.

Comment: yes this is the php response, and got a data object, that begins from response object.